# Delete these files10 million+ files in Windows server 2012, no pattern in the filenames

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I have windows 2012 server and it has 10M+ files in a directory from 2016 need your help to know how i can delete these files prior to OCT 2020.

Also I don't see anything common in filenames all have some different patterns

Eg:

LSP1COD$.10218072.
LSP9COD$.14320014.

referred some post and tried below command but it didn't work.

```
ForFiles /p "D:\Program Files (x86)\CA\" /s /d -365 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

Comment: forfiles is the way to go. Please tell us why it didn't work?

Answer (score -1):

Replace "del" by "echo" to see if the forfiles can handle the large amount of files.  Then there may be a problem with the spaces in the "Program Files (x86)" directory name.  Try using its short name (perhaps "progra~1")  or or replace "@file" by "@path".

Comment: Should be a comment since it is not an Answer